# Why is this implementation of CDI Producer not working?

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, java-ee-8

I want to use the java ee 8 injection framework. Because class PartnerMapperImpl is generated and I cannot modify it and put an annotation on it , I have to make use of CDI Producer.
So I just implemented it , but for some reason the injection does not work. Instead mapper is always null. I really do not know why. Thanks for your help.

This is my producer class and method:

```
@RequestScoped
    public class PartnerMapperImplProducer {
    
        @Produces
        @RequestScoped
        @PartnerQualifier
        public PartnerMapperImpl producePartnerMapperImpl() {
            return new PartnerMapperImpl();
        }
    }
```

This is the service where it should be injected:

```
@RequestScoped
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Inject
    @PartnerQualifier
    private PartnerMapper partnerMapper;

    public MyServiceImpl() {

    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething(Integer id, String name) {
   
              if(mapper == null)
              {
                   throw new Exception("Oh shit mapper is null");
              } 
    }
 }
```

This is the qualifier:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ FIELD, TYPE, METHOD })
public @interface PartnerQualifier {

}
```

This is bean.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

Comment: How are you using the `MyServiceImpl`? To be more specific, how are you obtaining a reference to it? If CDI recognized the injection point `@Inject @PartnerQualifier PartnerMapper` it will either inject something to it or complain *at deployment time*.

Comment: MyServiceImpl should be injected to MyService. But it is always null

Comment: If I interpret the classes correctly, `PartnerMapperImpl implements PartnerMapper`? Then try to declare `PartnerMapper` (*not* impl) as the return value of your producer method.

Comment: good try , What should it make a difference ? But anyway it did not help either

Comment: I suppose the fact that your `MyServiceImpl` has a field named `partnerMapper` and that you are later on checking that `mapper == null` (different names) is a typo, right?

Comment: But setting that typo aside, your setup looks correct which leaves the question of how exactly do you obtain a reference for `MyServiceImpl`? Because you need to let CDI give you the instance for it to be injected. Therefore, you need to `@Inject` it somewhere or use something like dynamic lookup to grab the object. Following line would also do the trick assuming req. context is active at the time of invocation - `CDI.current().getBeanManager().createInstance().select(MyServiceImpl.class).get()`

Comment: Could you provide information about the container you are using. Wildfly? Micro-Profile, weld-standalone? How do you start the container, what messages do you get during deployment if there is any.